# Why is 'require' PHP function rearranging my HTML?

Tags: php, html

I have implemented a verification system for my website, where every time the user requests a page, a PHP script is run that checks if the user is currently logged in. If not, then the user is redirected to a login page. This is done by having a single "redirect.php" file which is 'required' by each page, using the syntax `<?php require 'redirect.php' ?>`.

Every page that has the above statement has all the code in the `<head>` element removed and put at the beginning of the `<body>`. Also, a HTML entity is inserted in quotes: `"&#xFEFF; "`.

The result is that in DevTools my HTML looks like this:
[image: image of code in DevTools]

Whereas, in my editor, it looks like this:

```
<?php require 'redirect.php' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Stuff</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that the code inside the 'redirect.php' file is irrelevant because even if I empty that file I get the same odd behaviour. I've checked for invisible unicode characters that somehow made it into my code; there aren't any.

Does anyone know what this is and how to fix it?

If it helps, I'm with InfinityFree hosting.

Comment: When trying to debug the response from the server, don't look at the HTML in devtools. Right click on the page and choose "View page source" instead. What you see in devtools is what the browser uses, which could be modified (if the browser decides it needs to "fix" something with the source) while "View page source" will show you exactly what the server returns

Comment: Some background info & FAQ: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-utf8-bom.en.html

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks so much, I never thought to view the source. That displays the HTML as I wrote it. I believe an answer below explains why this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&#xFEFF;` is a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

The file you are requiring must be saved in a format that starts with one (typically UTF-8 With BOM).

It gets inserted into your output stream as a character. Since it isn't a character allowed before the start of the body element it implicitly starts the body element (as well as the html and head elements) and gets inserted at the start of it.

The DOM inspector then normalises it as an HTML entity because it isn't a visible character.

When the rest of the document is parsed, some of what you intended to be put in the head is backfilled through the HTML 5 error recovery rules.

---

Check your editor and make sure the file format you save the PHP files in doesn't include a BOM.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been answered, `&#xFEFF;` represents a Byte-Order-Mark (BOM). Quentin was so kind to clear this up early.

And as you have found out already, `<?php require 'redirect.php' ?>` is inserting it.

However with what you experience there is more. You've not shared your browser version, but a single BOM alone at the top of `redirect.php` would not result in the problem you were able to demonstrate (with a common browser).

Here's the differentiation:

It is true that there is an insertion of the BOM. However if it would be at the very beginning of the HTTP response body (the top of the document), it would not be shown in the browser nor via the devtools / in the DOM.

Next to the BOM there must be as well at least one additional character. And it must be positioned before a BOM.

That could be for example another BOM character (or some other whitespace or any other character).

This is important to note when you're looking forward to troubleshoot the issue, as it is most likely not `redirect.php` (alone), or it must not be at its very beginning, but somewhere there-in, e.g. another require/include.

This could result in a cleaning strategy that orders things differently:

Fix the other files first and then when the browser shows clean, fix the first file (so `redirect.php` second-last and then the file that has the `<?php require 'redirect.php' ?>` statement last).

(only an example, this depends on the concrete files in use which I don't know. point in case is it might appear clean by accident)

---

It might be fine in your usage scenario to keep the *one* BOM. Personally I would not suggest that, but with the browses and interoperability requirements you have, this can vary.

---

- https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-utf8-bom.en.html
- http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom5
- https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark#problems

Answer (score -1):

When I open open this code sample in VSCode and use DevTools the format never changes. Try wrapping your required file in quotes and parenthesis like the example below.

`<?php require("redirect.php")?>`

Answer (score -2):

DevTools shows the interpreted code. It's possible that your free host inject some ADs into your code. Look at your real source code with CTRL+U in your browser. This should show whats going on

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer since it just helps the OP debug the issue but not necessarily to solve it.